# Disallow private constructor invocation in friend function

Tags: c++, constructor, private, friend

Is there any way to not allow private construction in friend function, In case we do have private constructor with friend function in our class. Only Static method should be responsible for object creation and other than this compiler should flash error message

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class a
{

public:
    void see ()
    {

    cout<<"Motimaa";

    }
    static a& getinstance()
    {
        static a instance;
        return instance;
    }

private:
    a() {};
    friend void access();
};
void access ()
{
a obj;
obj.see();//still friend function can access
}

int main()
{

a::getinstance().see();

access();
return 1;

}
```

Comment: No. When you made it a friend, you assumed this function is doing the right thing. It can scribble all over your private variables; creating the object via private constructor should be the least of your worries if you can't trust its implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Friend functions can access all private members and variables, but there is a potential workaround for your problem, assuming you are trying to explicitly stop accidental use of the default constructor.

You could potentially make the default constructor kill the program.  Now, create a second constructor that takes at least one argument, even if it's a meaningless argument.

Here's an example:

```
private:
  a() { cerr<<"Invalid call to constructor for object a!"; exit(); };
  a(bool dummyArg) {}

public:
  static a& getInstance() {
    static a instance(true);
    return a;
  }
```

Comment: It seems to be good one to disallow friend function to accidentally construct the object by using default constructor .but still friend function can be invoked by : a obj(true);

Answer (score 0):

friend functions have access to all members of the befriended class.